# I am trying to find a complete vba algorithm for the solver addin in excel

Tags: excel, solver, vba

Just to reconfirm, I do not need the recorded macro of the solver add-in, however I need the complete vba algorithm. I would be extremely grateful If anyone have any such code (or a link to the code) and share it.
Thanks

Comment: I don't think Microsoft made this open source. Maybe you should just ask them directly.

Answer (score 0):

Solver is a proprietary product produced by FrontLineSolvers. It is not written in VBA.

See http://www.solver.com/ for details of their products and the names of the algorithms they use.